# Find the Fourier Transform of $ \frac{\sin (x)}{x}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I've been trying to find Fourier transform of that function.

What I got so far:
- The function is even, so the FT is of order $2$, and an involution.
- When we integrate the FT of that function over $\mathbb{R}$, we get $1$  (because FT of FT is the function itself, we put argument$=0~$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{\sin (x)}{x}=1$$ well known.

But I don't know how to precisely calculate FT of that function given as a  combination/mix of elementary functions. I tried also changing variables etc. yesterday but nothing worked. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Jean Marie - someone wrote a comment and deleted it. Now I deleted mine too.

Comment: This function is classical under the name "sinc" ("Cardinal sine")

Answer (score 1):

Let's first define $\operatorname{sgn}t$ as $1$ if $t>0$, $-1$ if $t<0$ and $0$ if $t=0$ so (by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-mathrm-dx-frac-pi) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404496/doubt-related-to-int-0-infty-frac-sin-axxdx-frac-pi2))$$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\sin tx}{x}dx=\pi\operatorname{sgn}t.$$

Because odd functions integrate to 0,
$$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\sin x}{x}\exp ikxdx=\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cos kxdx=\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\sin[(1+k)x]+\sin[(1-k)x]}{x}dx\\=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\operatorname{sgn}(1+k)+\operatorname{sgn}(1-k)\right)=\pi1_{(-1,\,1)}(x).$$

Comment: Your first equation is not evident.

Comment: @JeanMarie It's well-known; I'll see if I can edit in a link to a proof.

Comment: Well for $t=1$ its well known, otherwise the invariance of $dx/x$ under scaling by positive numbers and the fact that sin is odd gets you the rest of the way

Comment: I've edited in a link to $t=1$ followed by a link to treatment of the sign.

Comment: Very  nice - of course I knew how to prove this, but I'd never seen such a "direct" proof. Of course it's also a little scary, since the functions are not (absolutely) integrable; the fact that if  $f\in L^2$ then $\hat f(\xi)=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A f(t)e^{-i\xi t}dt$ a..e. is _very_ deep (Carleson's theorem).